# Insert row in pandas Dataframe based on Date Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe df and a list li, My dataframe column contains:

```
    Student     Score   Date  
    A             10      15-03-19
    C             11      16-03-19
    A             12      16-03-19
    B             10      16-03-19
    A             9       17-03-19
```

My list contain Name of all Student li=[A,B,C]
If any student have not came on particular day then insert the name of student in dataframe with score value = 0

My Final Dataframe should be like:

```
    Student   Score   Date
    A         10      15-03-19
    B         0       15-03-19
    C         0       15-03-19
    C         11      16-03-19
    A         12      16-03-19 
    B         10      16-03-19
    A         9       17-03-19
    B         0       17-03-19
    C         0       17-03-19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
li = list('ABC')

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Date'].unique(), li], names=['Date', 'Student'])
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Student']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
       Date Student  Score
0  15-03-19       A     10
1  15-03-19       B      0
2  15-03-19       C      0
3  16-03-19       A     12
4  16-03-19       B     10
5  16-03-19       C     11
6  17-03-19       A      9
7  17-03-19       B      0
8  17-03-19       C      0
```

Alternative is use left join with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and helper DataFrame created by `product`, last replace missing values by `fillna`:

```
from  itertools import product
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['Date'].unique(), li)), columns=['Date', 'Student'])
df = df1.merge(df, how='left').fillna(0)
print (df)
       Date Student  Score
0  15-03-19       A   10.0
1  15-03-19       B    0.0
2  15-03-19       C    0.0
3  16-03-19       A   12.0
4  16-03-19       B   10.0
5  16-03-19       C   11.0
6  17-03-19       A    9.0
7  17-03-19       B    0.0
8  17-03-19       C    0.0
```

Comment: Your Alternative worrks fine but the first solution is giving error:   Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: @souravkhanna - Exactly, first solution working only for unique values in index. So please use second solution.